# У меня есть код и файл с примерами, но ответ записывается в конце, а надо после каждого примера

Tags: python

код:

```
with open('name.txt', 'r+') as fl:
    lines = fl.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        q = eval(line)
        fl.write(' =')
        fl.write(' ')
        fl.write(str(q))
    fl.close()
```

файл:

```
5*10-45
12 + 4
123 // 2 +1
```

Answer (score 1):

name.txt

```
6 / 0
5*10-45
12 + 4
123 // 2 +1
```

код

```
dct =[]
with open('name.txt', 'r') as fl:
    lines = fl.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        try:
            q = eval(line)
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            q = 'делить на ноль нельзя'
        dct +=[(f'{line.strip()} = {q}\n')]
with open('name_1.txt', 'w') as fl:
    fl.writelines(dct)
```

name_1.txt

```
6 / 0 = делить на ноль нельзя
5*10-45 = 5
12 + 4 = 16
123 // 2 +1 = 62
```

Comment: А как сделать если делится на ноль то написать 'делить на ноль нельзя'?

Comment: Дополнил ответ.